# Enzyme testing for presence of a class set by CSS-In-JS in React

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

Been tasked with converting from SCSS in our app to CSS in JS style stylesheets. It's been a good learning experience for SCSS but i'm having an issue updating a test to correctly check for the presence of a specific class.
[SC of test code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oKjh.png)

This component, when provided hasError=true prop, will be given the hasError class alongside its normal class. the function 'cx' is provided by the 'classnames' library to selectively apply classes.
[SC of component code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agMd0.png)

I think the issue is that I am not targeting the class correctly in the test.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on [enzyme docs](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html) you should be able to find the class using:

```
expect(wrapper.find('.foo')).to.have.lengthOf(1);
```